# Selenium And PhantomJS Isn't Parsing Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, phantomjs

Im using Selenium and PhantomJS to search through java and I can't seem to get PhantomJS to enable javascript. Im trying to open a webpage which contains javascript. Before this worked for me but Im trying to get quicker results:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver.get(url);
```

Now this is what Im trying but it seems like javascript isnt being executed.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,"C:\\SOFTWARE\\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
driver.get(url);
```

I dont know what else to try, I want to use PhantomJS but if there's any other headless Javascript-enabled html parsers I'd like to know. HtmlUnitDriver worked fine except I need something faster or a solution to the PhantomJS issue.
Thank you

Comment: How do you know that JavaScript is not being executed?

Comment: @ArtjomB. If I run `driver.getPageSource()` on PhantomJS it gives me the same result that I would get if I run the page in a browser with javascript disabled.

Comment: I don't know the page, but have you tried waiting?

Comment: It was because I didnt set the useragent. For some reason the default browser version doesnt work with this webpage. Solved it now

Answer (score 0):

I solved the javascript problem. I had to specify the useragent for the webdriver by adding the line `caps.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");` to the capabilities. HtmlUnitDriver also only works with this particular webpage if you specify a non-default browser version.

I'm testing to see if there is a performance gain from using phantomjs, as this was my reason for switching to it in the first place, I'll report back with the results